# How to guard route path in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have the following route rules:

```
 path: 'school', component: ShellComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    children: [
      {path: 'education/documents', component: DocumentsComponent}]
```

How to forbid use open specific route paths like:

```
{path: 'education/documents', component: DocumentsComponent}]
```

if use has role admin or another?

Is it the same way to use custom middleware like: `canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create Gaurd File and You can update it based on your requirement**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private helper: HelperService, private auth: AuthService) { }

canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    if (this.auth.isLoggedIn) {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }
    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.helper.redirect('/');
    return false;
    }
}
```

**Use guard in Route files:**

```
{path: 'account',component: AccountComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
children: [
{
    path: 'account',
    component: AccountComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}
]
```

Comment: What does it mean: `@Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
})`

Comment: providedIn tells Angular that the root injector is responsible for creating an instance of the AuthGuard (by invoking its constructor) and making it available across the application.